# Ununderstood English-language joke

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes

In a song video made by an American acquaintance, there is a joke that I don't understand. Here is the context:

"Alfresco" and "Pentaho" are two non-competing software applications that can be used together. An Alfresco representative recently made a rap song where he talks about his "[tricked out Pentaho](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zchQFzKh1g&feature=player_detailpage#t=62s)". Is it a reference to rappers' pimped out cars? I am not sure I understand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You got the connection: it's a reference to something having all the bells and whistles. In this case, it's a fully configured instance of Pentaho.

At the risk of killing a funny reference with over-analysis, the joke is that it alludes to a common hip-hop trope of referring to *haters*, people who are jealous of one's success. This is evident earlier in the song you linked to, when he says:

> Playing World of Warcraft while they type up their code
>
> "But that's not good enough for 'enterprise mode'"
>
> So they laughed and they dissed and they acted like haters
>
> While we coded with the force like open-source Darth Vaders

"Haters hating" is a popular trope amongst nerds and geeks for ultimately unknown reasons (I say it's the repitition, but what do I know?), but it has at least some of its origins in Chamillionaire's ["Ridin'"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtwJvgPJ9xw&feature=artist). The song has the following hook:

> They see me rollin' they hatin'
>
> Trying to catch me ridin' dirty

Chamillionaire is making a reference to a somewhat American-specific racial issue of *[driving while black](http://www.aclu.org/racial-justice/driving-while-black-racial-profiling-our-nations-highways)*, where cops in some areas reportedly conduct [racial profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_profiling) and make inordinately more traffic stops for African-Americans.

But the song has sparked [several memes and image macros](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/they-see-me-rollin) and perhaps most famously the nerdy parody anthem by Weird Al Yankovic, ["White and Nerdy"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9qYF9DZPdw). In it, he takes "*Ridin'*"'s melody and replaces the lyrics with various references to geek culture.

You should see the connection between Weird Al's "White and Nerdy" and the video you linked: the joke is the juxtaposition of hip-hop culture concerned with serious racial issues with awkward white nerds who are primarily interested in geeky stuff like open-source projects.

That is to say, haters gonna hate a fully tricked out Pentaho instance.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that Pentaho is homophonic to *Pinto*, as found in the name of the *Ford Pinto*, a model of car.  You would understand the joke if you understood the reputation the *Pinto* once carried; no one living in the era it was sold, like my parents did, would ever describe a *Pinto* as "tricked out" -- a synonym for extravagantly furnished, by the way -- almost from the start it was derided for its numerous quality problems, to the point that *Time Magazine* rated the car one of the [50 worst cars of all time](http://www.time.com/time/specials/2007/article/0,28804,1658545_1658498_1657866,00.html).  Why? The gas tank was [prone to explosions](http://www.fordforums.com/f349/defective-pinto-almost-took-fords-reputation-40953/) after rear-end collisions, to the point that it was the Pinto which was implicated in the first case ever to be filed against a car manufacturer for criminal homicide.

Comment: I think you might've over-thought this: the Pinto connection is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: +1 Interesting! I actually tried to find a car brand that sounded like "Pentaho" but I had never heard about the Pinto, probably because I am European.

Answer (score 3):

I feel it is **MUCH** simpler than the other posts here

Penta-**HO** as in [Tricked out HO](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tricked%20out) (NSFW) - i.e. Whore, i.e. prostitute with all the trimmings
See Wikipedia - [Ho'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ho%27)

Comment: Thanks but I fail to see the connection between "penta" and "tricked out". Or is "Tricked out HO" used as-is?

Comment: @Nicolas: Tricked out HO is a prostitute with full make-up, bling-bling and so on - so the joke is pentaWhore (pronounced HO) pentaHO  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ho%27